# How to cout array values in c++

Tags: c++

am trying to cout all values in an array like this

```
int collect[8],c;
for(c = 0; c <= 4; c++)
{
    cout << "Enter First Number : ";
    cin >> collect[c];
}
cout << collect[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] << endl;
```

but it displays the last value. Please leave some note to make me understand why its not working

Comment: Array indexing doesn't work with multiple indexes. It's not a syntax error because you're using the 'comma operator', which evaluates to the last element. You need another for loop.

Comment: You got it right with `cin`. You need to do same with `cout` i.e. `cout << collect[c]` in a `for` loop.

Comment: Congratulations! You've met the `comma operator` seeing it working in full glory :-P ...

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ i saw the other question that looks just like mine. i dont understand it because am a noob to c++

Comment: @ChrysUgwu Effectively it means `collect[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` is actually equivalent to `collect[4]`.

Comment: okay cant i cout all of them with loop?

Comment: @ChrysUgwu With a loop of course you can: `for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) { cout << collect[i]; } cout << std::endl;`

Comment: sorry what if without a loop

Comment: @ChrysUgwu _"sorry what if without a loop"_ There's no _without a loop_, unless you provide an appropriate overload for `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const int[8])` and have the loop within the implementation of that overloaded function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65922/discussion-between-chrys-ugwu-and--).

Comment: @ChrysUgwu _"Let us continue this discussion in chat."_ Nope! I've said everything relevant.